# Can a typedef alias be unraveled at run-time?

Tags: c, typedef, preprocessor

Say one uses `typedef` to alias data types.
For example:

```
typedef int signed_integer;
typedef unsigned int unsigned_integer;
```

However, via pre-processor macros, `signed_integer` and `unsigned_integer` could be made aliases to other integer types and their unsigned counterparts (besides `int` and `unsigned int`), respectively. For example:

```
#define INTEGER_TYPE (3)
#define SHORT (1)
#define INT (2)
#define LONG (3)

#if INTEGER_TYPE == SHORT
typedef short signed_integer;
typedef unsigned short unsigned_integer;
#elif INTEGER_TYPE == INT
typedef int signed_integer;
typedef unsigned int unsigned_integer;
#elif INTEGER_TYPE == LONG
typedef long signed_integer;
typedef unsigned long unsigned_integer;
#endif
```

In the above example, the aliases are to `long` and `unsigned long`.
**My question is, what way if any is there to know at run-time what datatype the aliases alias to (ASSUMING IGNORANCE OF THE MACROS)?** Is there a way to go from `signed_integer` to something indicative of `long` for the example above, or `short` or `int` if the example is repurposed for the latter two?

I could easily make the determination at pre-processor time if I knew the macros that define the logical compilation, unfortunately for me, the library I'm working with does not make this obvious. If I knew the macros, I could write something like:

```
const char* IntegerTypeString(){
#if INTEGER_TYPE == SHORT
return "short";
#elif INTEGER_TYPE == INT
return "int";
#elif INTEGER_TYPE == LONG
return "long";
#endif
}
```

Comment: Assuming most standard/modern arches, this _might_ help: `switch (sizeof(unsigned_integer)) { case 2: return "short"; break; case 4: return "int"; break; case 8: return "long"; break; }` But, it's resolved at compile time because `sizeof(unsigned_integer)` is fixed/known at compile time. But, you were asking about "ignorance" of the macro. But, _why_ do you want to do this because you're defining a type and [I assume] all code will use it?

Comment: What problem do you try to solve

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm leaning towards implementing your suggestion as I know the, if you will, "fundamental" datatype, that being some integer or some floating-point of sorts for these `typedef` aliases. The reasoning for needing this is that I'm trying to interface a library with an exchange format. The files in the exchange format may be conveyed as 32-bit or 64-bit integers/floats. However, the library might configure its aliases to C types that are not suitable for those sizes, hence the need to know. This allows me to properly error out when the file is 64-bit but the integers are, say `int`.

Comment: Runtime it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_Generic` to test types:

```
typedef int Type;
#define Type    char


int main(void)
{
    _Static_assert(
        _Generic((Type) {0}, int: 1, default: 0),
        "Somebody screwed with Type.");
}
```

`(Type) {0}` is a compound literal that creates an object of type `Type`. The `0` in it needs to be a valid initializer for the desired type.

`_Generic` strips qualifiers (it uses the type as if it had undergone lvalue conversion), so this will not detect a change that adds qualifiers, such as changing `int` to `const int`. It also applies array-to-pointer conversion and function-to-pointer conversion.

Note that each enumerated type is compatible with some integer type, so it will not detect changes between those.

Comment: is generic runtime?

Comment: @0___________: The first operand of `_Static_assert` is a constant expression.

Comment: `_Generic` should also do it. Only "drawback" I see is that It constrains my compiler flags to be -std=c11 or higher (I'm using `gcc`).

Comment: @EricPostpischil but it still does not answer my question if it is runtime. I guess that it is still compile time.

Comment: @0___________: The `_Generic` is the first operand of a `_Static_expression`. The first operand of a `_Static_assert` is a constant expression. A constant expression can be evaluated at compile time. Therefore the `_Generic` can be evaluated at compile time.